# Control systems from a physicist's perspective

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, complex-systems, optimization

I am highly interested in the study of [control systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory). However it seems that almost all books are written by electronics or mechanical engineers.

Due to this they generally omit many things. For instance every single textbook in controls explains the DC motor, the RC circuit state space models. However I yet have to see a book that says something like,

Feedback loops in nature: When a car is being driven air resistance is proportional to speed and constitutes a 'natural' feedback without any op-amps or sensors etc...

and feedback loops in weather

https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2011/jan/05/climate-change-feedback-loops

if anyone knows of a book that addresses such matters that will be great!

Comment: The negative feedback loops that you are describing are "open loop", and are a consequence of the physics involved.  Are you interested in such "open loops", or are you interested in a process which has some type of electronic controller on it?

Comment: The ones you referred to as 'open loops'...

Comment: Perhaps to help delineate there is *control systems theory* where the intent is to control a system (usually by an engineer, designer) using *feedback theory*. I believe you are interested in feedback theory which as you mentioned is not limited to the realm of engineering systems, but understanding, analyzing and modeling them as well. Unfortunately textbooks will probably not give you what you want. But if you research published papers you may.

Comment: @DavidWhite  mother nature sometimes closes her own loop, and linear models can be written to illustrate the OP's examples indeed are closed loop systems. No sensors required. Of course though you need at least some initial energy input. Free fall in a planetary atmosphere is a feedback system that approaches the equilibrium of terminal velocity. A free fall starts with initial potential energy at some initial position and eventually reaches a constant velocity with some kinetic energy. Until you hit the ground.

Comment: @docscience, I actually did process control in industry, and the feedback involved was somewhat different than the OP is asking about.  For physical systems, most of them have negative feedback, and so, are stable.  The notable exception is exothermic reactors ... the reaction rate approximately doubles for each 10 C rise in temperature, which quickly exceeds the ability to remove heat from the system.  At some point, these systems "run away" due to their positive feedback.

Comment: @CodeStar, the control systems theory that you will find in text books does not answer the question that you are asking.  In addition, physical systems are normally described in a way that does not entail the usual concepts involved in control theory.  You will find that you can adapt the control theory found in textbooks to most physical processes, but it will definitely take you a while to gain an intuitive understanding of the control theory found in text books.

Comment: read this, it is very well written: Bechhoefer: "Feedback for physicists: A tutorial essay on control", REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS, VOLUME 77, JULY 2005, pp783-836

Comment: I can't recommend a book but I can recommend a fantastic [youtube playlist by Brian Douglas.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUMWjy5jgHK1NC52DXXrriwihVrYZKqjk)

Comment: @hyportnex I request you to write this review paper in answer section cause this paper fits the op request (don't dwell much on usual system found in control books for engineer, even provides some example relevant to physicist and goes to discuss things which are not usually provided in introductory control books)

Comment: @aitfel that article by Bechhoefer is a small book, it is 54 pages long tightly printed in font 10. I surely cannot write a summary of that work that would fit the customs of this platform. If the OP had a *specific* technical question that I might be able to answer. From your comment it appears that you have read it and maybe you can write a good summary. If so, then go ahead, it is your turn!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/Second_Edition) is a (free) book that you may be looking for:
Feedback Systems: An Introduction for **Scientists** and Engineers by Karl J. Åström and Richard M. Murray

From its preface I quote:

> This book provides an introduction to the basic principles
>   and tools for the design and analysis of feedback systems. It is intended
>   to serve a diverse audience of scientists and engineers who are
>   interested in understanding and utilizing feedback in physical,
>   biological, information and social systems. We have attempted to keep the
>   mathematical prerequisites to a minimum while being careful not to
>   sacrifice rigor in the process. We have also attempted to make use of
>   examples from a variety of disciplines, illustrating the generality of
>   many of the tools while at the same time showing how they can be applied in
>   specific application domains.

Answer (score 1):

**Nonlinear physics**
One area of physics that studies control systems is the nonlinear theory... although some may treat it as a branch of mathematics. The physics textbooks on nonlinear theory are usually full of the examples of systems with a feedback - from various types of generators and amplifiers, to non-linear equations (e.g., [Korteweg-de Vries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93De_Vries_equation)) for waves in liquids, to equations describing patterns formation (such as [Swift-Hoheberg equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift%E2%80%93Hohenberg_equation), with applications in clouds and QFT alike).

**Generators**
I have mentioned amplifiers and generators - these are the areas where the feedback is explicitly designed and studied. This ranges from simple motors to the circuits used in radio communication (where [Vand-der-Pol equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator) is the model par excellence) and to quantum generators, such as lasers and masers.

**Decision theory**
Another very mathematical prospective on control systems is from the point of veiw of statistics. Serious texts dealing with hypothesis testing and Bayesian statistics are essentially *physics-speak* for control theory.

**Summary**

- The feedback is so ubiquitous in physics, that it is likely to be covered in a separate book: one should either look for appropriate problems in a specific domain, or address the texts that are more mathematical but less specific about applications.
- Control theory often passes in physics under different names and with different terminology (e.g., nonlinear physics/oscillation theory, decision theory/statistics).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are control systems build for physical devices that need to be controlled. For instance, controlling an airplane or a missile requires control loops, where the forces one is dealing with are real physical effects (eg, the airflow past the aircraft, at each control surface). I remember doing some control theory for satellite attitude and orbit control. Do aerodynamics and you'll find plenty physical loops. Look up aircraft control books or papers and you'll find those. And actually, generalizing this applies to anything that moves (eg robotics, or your car example). Going further, it applies to any physical system that is changing.

The issue is that most control theory books generalize the theory, so you have to be able to find the mathematical expressions for your physical interactions. In any case it's normally implemented electronically (abstracting the control circuits to control eg aircraft control surfaces). The in depth control theory was developed for those kinds of applications.

I did not try to find the references, but wanted to place your question and a possible way to search in a broader context.